# Can't reach repo.msys2.org

Tags: windows, msys2

I'm trying to set up MSYS2 on Windows 10 but I'm getting the following error when running *pacman -Syu*

```
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw32.db' from repo.msys2.org : Operation too slow. Less than 1 bytes/sec transferred the last 10 seconds
```

I've tried *pacman -Sy*, *pacman -Syuu*, *pacman -S*, *pacman-mirrors*, *pacman -Su*, *pacman -Syu --disable-download-timeout*, and I've tried running autorebase.bat.
I've also tried using command prompt to ping repo.msys2.org and get no response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something is down with the repo.msys2.org repository right now.  This is happening on several CI Builds and local installations.  When this has happened before it usually clears up later.  So I would try again in a couple hours.

Comment: Thanks. I've had this issue since the day before I posted this. But maybe you're right and I just need to be more patient.

Comment: Here is the issue on the [mingw github](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/1884)

Comment: Thanks. I guess waiting is the solution then.

Comment: It's back up now

Answer (score 0):

Temporary workaround as long as the server is down: Uncomment the `repo.msys2.org` mirror from your `\etc\pacman.d` files (were in `C:\tools\msys64\etc\pacman.d` for me).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Was about to try it out but the site came back up anyway.